# Nginx - rewrite and pass_proxy to another port cause 404 not found

Tags: nginx, proxy, rewrite

Trying to let the url rewriting work in conjuction with the port forwarding but it seems doesn't work.

My application server is run at `:8080` port while the `nginx` works at default `80` one. So I'm forced not only to rewrite the urls but also forward the request to another port.

Actually, the only I'm trying to do is query the existing resource `http://localhost:8080/#/cat/tom` by it's shortcut `http://localhost/tom` without any redirect.

Here's what I made based on `nginx` doc and other questions:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /#/cat/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    ...
}
```

Have tried another configurations but neither does work. When I access the `http://localhost/tom` it says `404 not found` while the `http://localhost:8080/#/cat/tom` works as expected.

Logs are haven't any error mention.

How to force this work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `#/cat/tom` is an instruction to the client-side application and not the server-side application. Which means that it needs to be sent to the client (via a redirect).

For example:

```
location = /tom {
    return 302 /#/cat/tom;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    ...
}
```

You mention in your question that you are trying to do this without a redirect, but unfortunately if you look at the structure of a URL, you will notice that anything after the `#` is not sent to the server. See [this document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) for more.

Answer (score 2):

nginx rewrites work only on the path part of the URL. It does not work on the query part, which is separated by `?` nor does it work on the part separated by `#`, which is the fragment.

Actually, when entering your `http://localhost:8080/#/cat/tom` URL into your browser, your browser sends a request to get `http://localhost:8080/`, and your browser processes the part after `#`by itself.

So, you need to find out how exactly your application software works with these fragment parts, and make a configuration based on that.